# Kibana Rendering Issue

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an instance of elasticsearch up and running on my RHEL. I rebooted my host recently and ever since the graphs and bar charts are not showing up for a dashboard I had saved earlier. The index was the sample Shakespeare index I had loaded onto elastic search.

How do I know whats wrong? I'm a bit of a Linux Noob and so I was wondering if somebody could help me on what I need to do to troubleshoot the issue here?

Some questions I need answered are:

1. How do I start and stop my instance of Elasticsearch and Kibana? Is it done in one command or is it seperate for each?
2. When I reboot my host, does an index get wiped off elasticsearch? Should I re-index the data again?

Apologies if some of these questions are plain stupid and thanks in advance for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the json file that was indexed by ES. I think that was the root of the issue. So i restored that file, then deleted the index and reindexed the data in Kibana. It came back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different browser.  I had the same thing seemingly happen to me - no bar charts... though note when doing a mouse over, I saw context data as I dragged my mouse cursor over where the bars in the bar chart should have been.   I was using Chrome (showed no bar charts), but when I fired up Pale Moon (because it was there) I saw the bar chart just fine.  May be some rendering issue with a Chrome update.

It's not a satisfactory answer for me, but check it out.

Comment: I deleted the json file that was indexed by ES. I think that was the root of the issue. So i restored that file, then deleted the index and reindexed the data in Kibana. It came back to normal.